# Import and export of animation keys in Maya

Tags: python, beginner, file, serialization, pyqt

I have programming this importing and exporting of animation keys. It is working, but I would like to gather any feedback/advice as I am still pretty much a noob in coding.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class mainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300,200)
        self.initUI()
        self.createConnections()


    def initUI(self):
        self.importLbl = QLabel('Import Directory')
        self.importTxt = QLineEdit()
        self.openAnimBtn = QToolButton()
        self.importAnimBtn = QPushButton('Import ANIM')

        self.exportLbl = QLabel('Export Directory')
        self.exportTxt = QLineEdit()
        self.setAnimBtn = QToolButton()
        self.exportAnimBtn = QPushButton('Export ANIM')

        self.exportCombo = QComboBox()
        self.exportCombo.addItem('Use keyframe range from Time Slider')
        self.exportCombo.addItem('Use keyframe range from selection only')

        self.separator = QFrame()
        self.separator.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
        self.separator.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)

        gridLayout = QGridLayout()

        gridLayout.addWidget(self.importLbl, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.importTxt, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.openAnimBtn, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.importAnimBtn, 2, 1, 1, 2)

        gridLayout.addWidget(self.separator, 3, 1, 1, 2)

        gridLayout.addWidget(self.exportLbl, 4, 1, 1, 2)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.exportTxt, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.setAnimBtn, 5, 2, 1, 1)

        gridLayout.addWidget(self.exportCombo, 6, 1)

        gridLayout.addWidget(self.exportAnimBtn, 7, 1, 1, 2)

        self.setLayout(gridLayout)  
        self.setWindowTitle("IMPORT / EXPORT ANIMATION KEYFRAMES")


    def createConnections(self):
        # Connections for Import 
        self.connect(self.openAnimBtn, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.openFile)
        self.connect(self.importAnimBtn, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.importAnim)

        # Connections for Export
        self.connect(self.setAnimBtn, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setDirectory)
        self.connect(self.exportAnimBtn, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.exportFunc)


    def openFile(self):
        """ Module for importing in .txt anim files """

        fileFilters = "Text (*.txt)"
        fileList = cmds.fileDialog2(fileMode = 1, fileFilter = fileFilters, dialogStyle = 2)

        if fileList:
            stringConvert = ''.join(fileList)
            print "Imported File is opened from : %s" %stringConvert
            self.importTxt.setText(stringConvert)


    def importAnim(self):
        """ Module for importing and assigning anim. curves """

        selection = cmds.ls(selection = True)

        if len(selection) == 1:
            fileImportTxt = self.importTxt.text()
            if fileImportTxt == "":
                cmds.warning("Please input in the file directory")
            else:
                print ">>> Unloading any hidden or locked attributes"
                self.unlockAttr()

                fileObjImport = open(str(fileImportTxt), 'r')
                print fileObjImport
                fileLines = fileObjImport.readlines()
                print fileLines
                count = 0

                for line in fileLines:
                    lineCnt = fileLines[count]
                    lineSplit = str.split(lineCnt)
                    attrValue = lineSplit[0]
                    frameValue = lineSplit[1]
                    attrName = lineSplit[2]

                    cmds.setKeyframe( selection, value = float(attrValue), attribute = attrName, time =float(frameValue))

                    count +=1

                fileObjImport.close()
        else:
            cmds.warning("Please select an object")


    def unlockAttr(self):
        """ Check for any attributes that are locked / hidden """

        selection = cmds.ls(selection = True)
        for item in selection:
            cmds.setAttr( str(item) + ".translateX", lock = False, keyable = True)
            cmds.setAttr( str(item) + ".translateY", lock = False, keyable = True)
            cmds.setAttr( str(item) + ".translateZ", lock = False, keyable = True)
            cmds.setAttr( str(item) + ".rotateX", lock = False, keyable = True)
            cmds.setAttr( str(item) + ".rotateY", lock = False, keyable = True)
            cmds.setAttr( str(item) + ".rotateZ", lock = False, keyable = True)
            cmds.setAttr( str(item) + ".scaleX", lock = False, keyable = True)
            cmds.setAttr( str(item) + ".scaleY", lock = False, keyable = True)
            cmds.setAttr( str(item) + ".scaleZ", lock = False, keyable = True)
            cmds.setAttr( str(item) + ".visibility", lock = False, keyable = True)


    def setDirectory(self):
        """ Module for exporting in .txt anim files """

        fileFilters = "Text (*.txt)"
        fileList = cmds.fileDialog2(fileMode = 0, fileFilter = fileFilters, dialogStyle = 2)

        if fileList:
            stringConvert = ''.join(fileList)
            print "Exported Directory is located at : %s" %stringConvert
            self.exportTxt.setText(stringConvert)


    def exportAnim(self, minTime, maxTime):

        selection = cmds.ls(selection = True)

        if len(selection) == 1:
            fileExportTxt = self.exportTxt.text()
            if fileExportTxt == "":
                cmds.warning("Please set where the file should be save")
            else:
                fileObjExport = open(str(fileExportTxt), 'w')
                selection = cmds.ls(selection = True)
                selectionConvert = ''.join(selection)
                dataCapture = []

                attributes = ['translateX', 'translateY', 'translateZ', 'rotateX', 'rotateY', 'rotateZ', 'scaleX', 'scaleY', 'scaleZ']

                for time in range(int(startTime) , int(endTime) +1):
                    cmds.currentTime(time)
                    for eachAttribute in attributes:
                        attrCapture = cmds.getAttr( selectionConvert + '.' + eachAttribute)
                        attrConvert = str(attrCapture)
                        timeCapture = str(time)
                        dataCapture.append(attrConvert + ' ' + timeCapture + ' ' + eachAttribute + ' ' + selectionConvert + ' \n')
                for lines in dataCapture:
                    fileObjExport.writelines(lines)
                fileObjExport.close()

        else:
            cmds.warning("Please select an object")


    def comboSel(self):
        """ Based on the selection in the combobox to grab the range values """

        global startTime
        global endTime

        selection = cmds.ls(selection = True)

        objInt = self.exportCombo.currentIndex()

        if objInt == 0:
            print "Using the scene range (Time Slider)"
            startTime = cmds.playbackOptions(query = True, minTime = True)
            endTime = cmds.playbackOptions(query = True, maxTime = True)

        else:
            print "Using the range of animated keyframes on the selection"
            startTime = cmds.findKeyframe(selection, which = 'first')
            endTime = cmds.findKeyframe(selection, which = 'last')

        return startTime
        return endTime


    def exportFunc(self):
        """ Function of the ExportAnim button """

        self.comboSel()
        self.exportAnim(startTime, endTime)


def main():
    global app 
    global form
    app = qApp
    form = mainWindow()
    form.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The code must remain embedded in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Avoid wildcard imports

Don't use wildcard imports like this:

> ```
> from PyQt4.QtCore import *
> from PyQt4.QtGui import *
> ```

Quoting from [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.

I guess you do this because you're using many classes from these modules.
A better way would be to do like this:

```
import PyQt4.QtCore as core
import PyQt4.QtGui as gui
```

This way you will have to prefix all the classes you used with `core.` or `gui.` appropriately, but it's better because it will be clear where everything comes from,
and automated tools can warn you when you try to use a name that doesn't exist.

#### Avoid using `global`

The abuse of the `global` keyword is especially clear in the `exportFunc` and `comboSel` methods:

> ```
> def exportFunc(self):
>     """ Function of the ExportAnim button """
>
>     self.comboSel()
>     self.exportAnim(startTime, endTime)
> ```

This method makes use of `startTime` and `endTime` globals which are set in `comboSel`. You should rewrite this to make `comboSel` return a tuple, and use that instead of globals:

```
def exportFunc(self):
    """ Function of the ExportAnim button """

    startTime, endTime = self.comboSel()
    self.exportAnim(startTime, endTime)
```

Then in `comboSel`:

```
def comboSel(self):
    # no no !
    #global startTime
    #global endTime

    # ...

    return startTime, endTime
```

Review all the uses of `global` in the rest of the code and try to eliminate all.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, greatly appreciated it! While trying out your solution, it works but as I tried to edit my existing code in a similar fashion (http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zfqQdL2r) I am getting an error - `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` in the exportFunc `startTime, endTime = self.comboSel()` and it would seems that it is due to the return statement of mine in `comboSel`. Hence I would like to ask, what exactly is the difference between the return statement of mine as compared to yours?

Comment: By the way, I noticed that in my code, when I am importing in the anm file - `openFile` function, my editor is displaying these a few lines which are `PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.ChildPolished`, `QFileDialog`, `PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.ChildRemoved`. As such are there any ways in which I can hide this, or did I perhaps did somewhere wrong?

Comment: Hm, unfortunately I don't know...

Comment: Okay. I thought I may have some insights regarding it. Thanks again, janos!